# Get twig file content and pass variables

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

I'm planning to create a function that sends an email but my concern is that I need to get my email template and pass variables inside.

For now this is what I got :

```
$template = $this->view->render('./partials/email-template.twig',['name'=>'sample']);
```

but I'm getting this error :

> *Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Views\Twig::render() must implement interface*
>   *Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\master\app\Controllers\Admin\VoucherController.php on
>   line 34*

Comment: You are providing the wrong data to the `render()` method. Read the exception message carefully and follow the documentation of Slim https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/return-twig-template-by-controller/890/9) you would need to use `fetch` first, e.g.

```
$template = $this->view->fetch('./partials/email-template.twig');
$html = $template->render(['name' => 'sample', ]);
```

Comment: For now  Im getting a null in the console. I think my path is wrong. What is the best way for pointing the email-template.twig directory from my controller directory?

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, the first argument has to be the $response.

Example given:

```
// Define named route
$app->get('/renderEmail/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, './partials/email-template.twig', [
        'name' => $args['name']
    ]);
})->setName('renderEmail');
```